# Date and time picker done button alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: This image is correct on when i used in one of my app]

[image: In this image done button gets differ from first image, i dont know why this happen]

I have used date and time picker library

```
import com.fourmob.datetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;
import com.sleepbot.datetimepicker.time.RadialPickerLayout;
import com.sleepbot.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog;
```

i had used this library in two different app,but in one app done button is looks correct but in another app done button looks differ ,please give me a solution to fix this.

Comment: add android:layout_margin="10dp" in button tags in xml.

Comment: button is not in user defined xml file, its library

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to customize the date picker dialog, I suggest to use some custom date picker library.

However, if you wish to have the system look & feel for the date / time picker dialog, I would recommend using [this](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker).

The idea is - if you've the source code for the layouts, you'll have better control over the layout / display and can customize as required.

Comment: I had already used the library which you have said, Am asking the question in this library alone. please see this link "https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker/issues"  and "https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker/issues/130"

Comment: I assume you're using this library by declaring in the gradle file, right? You haven't added the library's code to your project as a dependent module, right?

Comment: Try adding the code of the library as a dependent module and you'll be able to modify the layout as required.

Comment: But actually i have used same code for both app but i get alignment problem in one app laone.

Comment: I think, in the app where it appears different, your code might be referring to the `id` of that button somewhere which causes it to appear different in the other app. Crosscheck the `id` of the `Done` button to verify if its references / modified in the app.